# estoy tratando de encontrar una forma que el programa me diga cuando una palabra tiene 2 vocales seguidas con ciclo while

Tags: python

Que sea con while y que no tenga el operador in por favor

```
print("programa que entrega una lista de substrings con la cantidad de vocales seguidas")
palabra1=input("escribir la 1ra palabra que desea")
palabra2=input("escribir la 2da palabra que desea")
palabra3=input("escribir la 3ra palabra que desea")
Lista=[palabra1.split, palabra2.split, palabra3.split]
ocurrencias= Lista.count(VOCALES)
```

Comment: Eso parece una tarea. Aquí no hacemos tareas.

Comment: ósea si, pero no es evaluado.